# google analistics.js for one page website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a webite that is one page website with Javascript routing.

in the address bar when you click buttons you get the following links:

/index.html#!/page_ABOUT_MAIN
/index.html#!/page_ENDORSEMENTS
etc.

the page is not reloaded and hits to those pages are not counted. Default google analistics counts only hits to index.html
I need to count those pages as separate hits.
Here what I have so far:

Menu code:

```
  <li><a href="#!/page_WHATIS" class="link1">What is The Rainbow Bridge?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!/page_ABOUT" class="link2">About The Author</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!/page_CONTACT_INFO" class="link3">Contact Info</a></li>
```

javascript code:

```
 /// analistics stats
     function addListener(element, type, callback) {
     if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
     else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
     }

     var link1 = document.getElementsByClassName('link1');
     var link2 = document.getElementsByClassName('link2');
     var link3 = document.getElementsByClassName('link3');

     addListener(link1, 'click', function() {
       ga('send', 'pageview', '#!/page_WHATIS');
     });

     addListener(link2, 'click', function() {
       ga('send', 'pageview', '#!/page_ABOUT');
     });

     addListener(link3, 'click', function() {
       ga('send', 'pageview', '#!/page_CONTACT_INFO');
     });
```

Unfortunately it is not functional:( Any help is highly appreciated.

Url: http://www.metamorphozis.com/test/html5/index2.html

Comment: Silly question I know, but I must ask just in case- have you got the Google Analytics JS code referenced?

Comment: sure:)it is on the same page, last version from analistics admin panel

Comment: Cool- just had to check :) try the code in the Answer unobf posted, but I do have some code very similar to what you posted above that I used for the same purpose you are trying to achieve. I will try and find it and post it as an answer.

Comment: may I see your answer please?

Comment: Sorry, it's midnight here so heading to bed. I'll Keep looking and post it tomorrow (I know I've got it). Sorry I know this isn't awfully convenient :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is what I did:

javascript:

```
  function mylink(string) {
     ga('send', 'pageview', string);
  }
```

html code:

```
 <a href="#!/page_SPLASH" onclick="mylink('#!/page_SPLASH')">Home</a><br />
 <a href="#!/page_ABOUT_MAIN" onclick="mylink('#!/page_ABOUT_MAIN')">About</a>
 <a href="#!/page_WHATIS" onclick="mylink('#!/page_WHATIS')">What is?</a>
```

now analysts counts virtual pages. Thank you all, who helped me to solve this question.  Although unobf answer did not helped me, I got my error due to his code:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function postGoogleAnalytics(string) {
    var tid = 'YOUR TRACKING ID';
    var domain = 'www.example.com';
    jQuery.ajax('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=' +
        tid +
        '&cid=555&t=pageview&dh=' +
        domain +
        '&dp=' +
        encodeURIComponent(string), {
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
}
```

You would then change your calls to do

```
addListener(link1, 'click', function() {
  postGoogleAnalytics('page_SPLASH');
});
```

Comment: not sure if I use this code correctly. can I give you url so you could take a look?

Comment: Yes, please put the URL in your question

Comment: In which source code file do you have the code to post to Google Analytics?

Comment: it is actually in footer of index.html Search /// analistics stats comment to see it

Comment: I added an example of how to change your listeners, are you seeing data being captured in your Google analytics?

Comment: unobf, thank you for your help:) it turned out I had an error in listener part so I've changed added onclick action and everything worked correctly